# Running unidentified developer Applications as a Non-administrator

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, administrator, privileges

I am used to Windows but recently started using a restricted(can't run apps from unidentified developers) OS X machine and want to make it full featured without having to reformat, reset/recreate admin, etc.

I have MagicPrefs installed by just putting the file in a Programs folder under my user account and it just runs  but gedit has a unidentified developer error and even a right click open requires admin privileges (I can not turn off gatekeeper from System Preferences)

Portable versions of OS X applications might be a solution for major apps.

Comment: Is it just me or are you asking about ways to bypass security protocols that have been put in place? I'm not saying it's a bad question, though getting someone to give you this info probably won't happen. Unless of course I am misunderstanding the question and this is all for purely "academic" reasons.

Comment: @Josiah I think you see the gray area here. These applications such as gedit are perfectly fine applications that would run if not for the unidentified developer issue but as it stands... It is more of a question of OS X and what kind of applications are available to use that have this type of restriction. For example a .dmg, package, etc are sort of new concepts for me. MagicPrefs worked great and I want to know why that is.

Comment: There are definitely many legit applications that simply don't bother to pay the $100 to get "Apple-approved" signing. I know I don't. However, the "unidentified developer" error exists because of Gatekeeper. In order to bypass it you would need an Admin password. I am simply wondering why you really want to bypass this security on a school computer. You could buy your own laptop if you wanted too. :) As for file types, any .app that is not signed will give you that error. `.dmg`s are basically like cut-off folders from the rest of the world. They just hold something. .app is the issue.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything you can do about it. But perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @Josiah In windows there are ways to sign your own drivers, is there a way to sign a app (I will look into it)? I do have my own PC, but the norm at school is using that laptop and certain mac only applications already pre installed. Installing/running a few applications such as a ftp, code editor, etc would be nice.

Comment: No, the app is signed by the developer when you have the source available. I do not believe it is possible to "self-sign" things, but there might be something on Stackoverflow about that.

Comment: Perhaps see this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

The only way to 'self sign' an app for Gatekeeper is to enroll in the Apple Developer Program (currently $100/annually), sign up for a code-signing certificate, and install XCode to create "your" app.

You could then create an App in XCode and just include the contents of the other app you *really* are wanting to run in your app bundle, then sign it with your certificate. This app would able to launch anywhere (though you would possibly be violating the license of the original software).

Obviously this is not very practical. The method suggested in another answer here to copy the contents to another app's bundle will not, in itself, circumvent Gatekeeper. The 'Known Developer' check requires the the app bundle to contain a `_CodeSignature` subfolder, and an app ID which corresponds to the signed developer in the bundle's `Info.plist` file. Both of these will be destroyed if you replace all the contents, and selectively replacing the contents will result in an app which has a code signature that does not match that of the app it is claiming to be.

If this 'transplant' method does work, it is not because it tricks Gatekeeper; rather because it prevents Gatekeeper from ever being invoked. Regardless of whether an app bundle is signed, the Gatekeeper system will only check apps that are 'quarantined'. This means an extended attribute flag has been added to the file which indicates it was downloaded from the internet or else-wise from an unknown source. Safari and Mail will add this flag to downloaded files, but there is no requirement that all apps must behave this way. You can see this flag by running the command `ls -l@` on the directory containing your app bundle:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 self  wheel      102 Jul  7  2013 My Sketchy App.app
    com.apple.quarantine         57
```

If you copy the contents of an app into another app's bundle, the newly-created app has whatever extended attributes the bundle did beforehand. So if it did not have a `quarantine` flag, neither will your new app and you will be able to launch it. But if it *did* have a `quarantine` flag, it still will, and Gatekeeper will be in effect.

Transplanting the app contents is just a roundabout way of removing this flag. You can accomplish the same thing by simply removing the `quarantine` flag from the app directly, like so:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "./My Sketchy App.app"
```

or you could indirectly remove the `quarantine` flag by launching/allowing the app on another Mac (which does not have Gatekeeper restrictions in effect, or where you have an admin account which allows you to override it), then copying it to the restricted machine via a method that does not recreate the flag (apps copied from a SMB share, for example, will not be quarantined).

Long story short: the right-click 'Open' (or "Open Anyway" from Security screen of System Preferences) adds an exception to Gatekeeper for the app in question, which requires admin privileges. Removing the `quarantine` flag from an app only requires write permissions to the app bundle, and prevents Gatekeeper from ever getting involved.

Comment: The `xattr` quarantine flag removal command is **so** useful... tysm!

Answer (score 2):

Take an application you normally run, like one from the app store or the internet. Make sure you have permission to change it. For this, I recommend downloading a simple internet application like Keka, and dragging it to your desktop.

Duplicate the application by right clicking on it and selecting Open Package Contents. Drag out the contents of the application and fill the empty app shell with the content of the application from a unidentified developer.

The system reads it as an application created by a identified developer, and you can run it normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Right click" to the app
2. Click to "Show Package Contents"
3. Navigate to "Contents/MacOS"
4. Then pull the executable (What is in the "MacOS" folder) to Terminal.app
5. And finally press "Enter" (If everything works the application will start)